# In IF statement, condition on the number of groups AND the number of observations per group

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

How do I in a IF statement condition on the number of groups AND the number of observations per group? I.e. if >=4 groups are present AND with >=2 observations, do something.

The first part is less tricky, it's the second part I'm really struggling with.

```
library(tidyverse)
data(mtcars)

set.seed(123)

mtcars <- mtcars %>% rownames_to_column("type")
mtcars$brand <- stringr::str_split_fixed(mtcars$type, " ", 2)[,1]
mtcars <- mtcars[mtcars$brand %in% c("Merc","Mazda","Hornet","Toyota"),]

mtcars_ls <- vector("list",5)
for(n in 1:5){ mtcars_ls[[n]] <- mtcars[mtcars$type %in% sample(mtcars$type, size=15, replace=T),]}

for(i in seq_along(mtcars_ls)) {
  if( length(unique(mtcars_ls[[i]]$brand)) >= 4 ) { next } 
  else { mtcars_ls[[i]] <- NULL } 
}

mtcars_ls
[[1]]
                type  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  brand
1          Mazda RX4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  Mazda
2      Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  Mazda
5  Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 Hornet
9           Merc 230 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2   Merc
10          Merc 280 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4   Merc
11         Merc 280C 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4   Merc
12        Merc 450SE 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3   Merc
14       Merc 450SLC 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3   Merc
20    Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1 Toyota
21     Toyota Corona 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1 Toyota

[[2]]
                type  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  brand
1          Mazda RX4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  Mazda
2      Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  Mazda
5  Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 Hornet
8          Merc 240D 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2   Merc
11         Merc 280C 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4   Merc
12        Merc 450SE 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3   Merc
13        Merc 450SL 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3   Merc
20    Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1 Toyota
21     Toyota Corona 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1 Toyota

[[3]]
                type  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  brand
1          Mazda RX4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  Mazda
2      Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  Mazda
4     Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 Hornet
5  Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 Hornet
8          Merc 240D 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2   Merc
9           Merc 230 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2   Merc
10          Merc 280 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4   Merc
12        Merc 450SE 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3   Merc
13        Merc 450SL 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3   Merc
14       Merc 450SLC 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3   Merc
20    Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1 Toyota
21     Toyota Corona 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1 Toyota

[[4]]
                type  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  brand
1          Mazda RX4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  Mazda
2      Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  Mazda
4     Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 Hornet
5  Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 Hornet
8          Merc 240D 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2   Merc
9           Merc 230 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2   Merc
10          Merc 280 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4   Merc
11         Merc 280C 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4   Merc
13        Merc 450SL 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3   Merc
14       Merc 450SLC 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3   Merc
20    Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1 Toyota
```

The above code removes any list with less than 4 car brands present. What I really want it to do is to remove lists with less than 4 car brands AND with 2 observations per car brand. In the above example, this would only leave `mtcars_ls[[3]]`.

Comment: With the RNG seed you are using I'm getting no list member with at least 2 observations per brand.

Comment: I just re-started RStudio and pasted in the example code, and I got the same output as before, with mtcars_ls[[3]] having at least 2 observations per car brand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to filter it and don't need to know the index, you can use `keep`. If you need to know the index, replace `keep` with `map_lgl` and use `which` on the resulting logical vector.

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars_ls %>% 
  keep(~ {
    count(., brand) %>% 
      {nrow(.) >= 4 & all(.$n >= 2)}
  })
#                 type  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  brand
# 1          Mazda RX4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  Mazda
# 2      Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  Mazda
# 4     Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 Hornet
# 5  Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 Hornet
# 8          Merc 240D 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2   Merc
# 9           Merc 230 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2   Merc
# 10          Merc 280 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4   Merc
# 12        Merc 450SE 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3   Merc
# 13        Merc 450SL 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3   Merc
# 14       Merc 450SLC 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3   Merc
# 20    Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1 Toyota
# 21     Toyota Corona 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1 Toyota
```

Answer (score 0):

One think you could do is use some of the `purrr` functions like `map`. You then write a function specifying the checks you want for each data frame like below:

```
# Note I am using 1 car per brand just so I get results
# This is a parameter so it is easily changed based on your constraints

check_list <- function(df, num_brands = 4, cars_per_brand = 1){
  unique_cars <- unique(df$brand)
  min_n <- min(count(df, brand)[["n"]])

# Why any? Because you could return multiple minimum values. 
  if(unique_cars >= num_brands && any(min_n>cars_per_brand)){
    df
  } 
}

map(mtcars_ls, check_list)
```

The output is then:

```
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
             type  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  brand
8       Merc 240D 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2   Merc
10       Merc 280 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4   Merc
12     Merc 450SE 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3   Merc
13     Merc 450SL 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3   Merc
14    Merc 450SLC 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3   Merc
20 Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1 Toyota
21  Toyota Corona 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1 Toyota

[[4]]
             type  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  brand
1       Mazda RX4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  Mazda
2   Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  Mazda
8       Merc 240D 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2   Merc
9        Merc 230 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2   Merc
11      Merc 280C 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4   Merc
12     Merc 450SE 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3   Merc
14    Merc 450SLC 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3   Merc
20 Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1 Toyota
21  Toyota Corona 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1 Toyota

[[5]]
NULL
```

You can then specify additional details, etc, and this eliminates the need for the loop.

You can then use the `compact` function to remove the NULL lists, too.

Answer (score 0):

What about this one:

```
ff <- function(dtt){
    dtt %>% filter(duplicated(brand)) %>%
        filter(!duplicated(brand)) %>% nrow() >= 4
}

mtcars_ls[sapply(mtcars_ls, ff)]

# [[1]]
#                 type  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb  brand
# 1          Mazda RX4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  Mazda
# 2      Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  Mazda
# 4     Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 Hornet
# 5  Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 Hornet
# 8          Merc 240D 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2   Merc
# 9           Merc 230 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2   Merc
# 10          Merc 280 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4   Merc
# 12        Merc 450SE 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3   Merc
# 13        Merc 450SL 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3   Merc
# 14       Merc 450SLC 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3   Merc
# 20    Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1 Toyota
# 21     Toyota Corona 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1 Toyota
```